# How to reference a 'var' from one method in another?

Tags: c#, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, poco, var

I know that a var is only in scope within it's method. But I've came across the situation where the collection 'var' from a database connection method, needs to be accessed in a subsequent Query() method in order to make a query.

The specific error is: `The name collection doesn't exist in the current context`

I've been referencing the [MongoDB C# driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/getting_started/quick_tour/) in order to set up the connection and the query and all seems correct besides this issue.

Does anyone know how I can restructure my code to resolve the error?

My two methods are specified as follows in an OrderRespository class, that makes database connections and queries:

```
//Method to create MongoDB Orders connection and get handle on collections
    public static bool CreateConnection()
    {

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        try
        {
          var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
          //Get a handle on the customers collection:
          var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("customers");
        }
        catch(MongoConnectionException)
        { 
            return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    }



    //Method to test query on database documents
    public async static Task<List<Customer>> FindCustomers()
    {
        var documents =  await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
        List<Customer> customerList = await documents.ToListAsync();

        return await documents.ToListAsync();

    }
```

And this is the customer Model POCO class that models the collection fields:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This attribute is used to map the Id property to the ObjectId in the collection
        /// </summary>
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("firstName")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("lastName")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variable outside the methods, right inside the OrderRepository definition? That should give it global scope.

Comment: Make it a static property (or field) of the class (with the appropriate type, not `var`) or else pass it from one method to the other as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateConnection` should *return the collection that it's creating* so that the person creating the connection can actually use it:

```
//Consider renaming this method; you're really here to get the customers,
//not create a connection
public static YourCollectionType<BsonDocument> CreateConnection()
{
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
    //Get a handle on the customers collection:
    return database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("customers");
}
```

`FindCustomers` can then accept the collection as a parameter:

```
public async static Task<List<Customer>> FindCustomers(
    YourCollectionType<BsonDocument> collection)
{
    var documents =  await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
    List<Customer> customerList = await documents.ToListAsync();

    return await documents.ToListAsync();
}
```

You can then use `CreateConnection` to create the documents that you search through:

```
var customers = FindCustomers(CreateConnection());
```

If `FindCustomers` is something that would only ever make sense to use with a collection created by `CreateConnection` and you won't ever use the created object for anything else, then you could have `FindCustomer` call `CreateConnection` directly, but odds are those conditions won't apply.

Comment: I tried to implement the above, and figured out its an IMongoCollection that is the type required by the Api ref. I still have two errors which I'm not sure of..highlighted in this paste: http://hastebin.com/jeletobese.php  @Servy

Comment: @BrianJ I had a typo in my original revision; I edited the post a little while ago to fix it.

Comment: Updated..seen your edit above, the ToListAsync() didn't exist in the document. So I changed that to a ToList() and removed the await notations. But I still have one set of errors left stating an implicit conversion error. This is the updated paste with error detail:  http://hastebin.com/huwabiraji.tex

Comment: @BrianJ You have a list of BsonDocuments, not a list of Customers.  You can't assign a list of BsonDocuments to a list of Customers for the same reason that you can't treat a list of Apples as if it's a list of Oranges.

Comment: Okay I'm assuming I just need to cast the Bson doc to a list then. Before I make this assignment. Any hints on how to cast that?

Comment: I mean a customer list, any hints on doing that cast?

Comment: @BrianJ Casting is a way of informing the compiler that the object that you have is actually something different than it thinks that it is, for example, if you have an `Animal` object you can cast it to a `Tiger` *if it's really a `Tiger`.  If you don't have a `Tiger`, then the cast will just fail at runtime.  You can't cast a `Mouse` into a `Tiger`, it just won't work.

Comment: So what would be the best solution in this case to map the reutrned Bson to my Customer POCO? I've never really came across this situation before

Comment: @BrianJ You're going to have to create a method yourself to pull whatever information is in the `BsonDocument` and put it in your `Customer` object.

Comment: Okay, I'm just Googling this tag from my Customer POCO, [BsonElement("firstName")]  I think it provides a mapping between the Bson doc and my Customer list. I've accepted your answer besides as it's mostly correct apart from the FindCustomer()